# Try Manual Connection

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have a form with fields to make a connection to the database using CodeIgniter. The data is filled in by the users in the form.
Is it possible to know if the connection is established or not?

```
$drive      = $this->input->post('drive');
$hostname   = $this->input->post('hostname');
$database   = $this->input->post('database');
$username   = $this->input->post('username');
$password   = $this->input->post('password');
$base       = $this->input->post('base');

$db = array(
                'hostname' => $hostname,
                'username' => $username,
                'password' => $password,
                'database' => $database,
                'dbdriver' => $drive,
                'db_debug' => FALSE);

       $cn =  $this->load->database($db);

if ($cn) { echo 'ok'; } else {echo 'nops';}
```

Comment: If CI is not reporting a DB error, then the connection is made - try running a simple query to test it

Comment: Is impossible, because i put wrong data to make login, and the print_r of $this->db showing just the wrong data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are explicitly disabling error messages with the `'db_debug' => false`, so I don't think you will get CI complaints. However you can do [the same as the Database library does](https://github.com/EllisLab/CodeIgniter/blob/2.1-stable/system/database/DB_driver.php#L118) for connection testing (since every field is public):

```
// your original code here
$conn_success = $cn->conn_id ? true : false;
```